# Cannot Upload Image from Android Tablets

Tags: java, android

Recently I am developing an Android application which has the functionality to upload the photo taken to the Web server. The code to upload the image is

```
URL url = new URL(AideApplication.SERVER + "upload/" + application.getUuid());
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
Log.i("Upload head image", "URL = " + url);

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + headImageFile.length());
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

The server code runs in Tomcat, the code is

```
private void handleUpload(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = req.getInputStream();
    File headImageDir = new File("headImages");
    File headImageFile = new File(headImageDir, "test.jpg");
    headImageFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(headImageFile);
    byte[] content = new byte[1024];
    System.out.println("Begin reading...");
    int read = is.read(content), sum = 0;
    System.out.println("First read: " + read);
    while(read != -1 && sum < length) {
        sum += read;
        fos.write(content, 0, read);
    read = is.read(content);
    System.out.println("Reading " + read + " bytes");
    }
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("Reading finishes: " + sum + " bytes in total");
}
```

The problem is: even though I set the timeout to be 10 min, I still cannot read any thing from the inputstream. It means that I got an "Begin reading...", then the function is blocked for 10 min and throws an timeout exception without "First read: ...".

I try to ping the Web server from the Android device, the Internet connection is OK; I also try to run the upload code locally in my PC, there is no problem and I can finish uploading quickly. It really confuses me because it has no problem to do some other HTTP POST operation with parameter body, but I don't know why it doesn't work in sending bytes. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the uploadFile() implementation here: http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106. I do however suggest using the HttpClient from apache though. Much easier to use and arguably more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using utils file from apache commons package for uploading images/files.